# ASP Index.cshtml is calling IndexAsync twice and second time Session Variables are gone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I've looked through some examples, but they don't seem to be helping.

I have an index page that redirects to another controller on button click. The controller gathers database records before displaying its view, so it needs to be async.

This action always happens twice. (Developer system, one user, so it isn't some multiuse conflict)

I thought it might be a double click issue since there is an async call being made. But I changed my code to account for this and it still happens.

Here is the Button:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <button type="submit" id="ViewHoursbutton" name="ViewHours" class="btn btn-primary button-bottom" >View Hours</button>
</div>
```

Here is the button click script:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
 {
    $("#ViewHoursbutton").one("click", function () 
      {
          window.location.href = "/ETime?EmployeeID=" + employeeID;
     });
});
```

Here is my controller with the IndexAsync:

```
public class ETimeController : BaseController
{
    private List<TrackingItems> _trackingItems = new List<TrackingItems>();
    private Employee _OnEmployee; // The employee we are working with
    [HttpGet]

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync(string EmployeeID)
    {

        if (EmployeeID == null)
        {
            // return error 205
            return NoContent();
        }
        TrackingItems TrackingDB = new TrackingItems();
        // grab a month of data or so. 
        var trackingItems = await TrackingDB.GetTrackingItems(
            EmployeeID,
            DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30),
            DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));

        dynamic DynModel = new ExpandoObject();
        _OnEmployee = GetSessionObject("CurrentEmployee");
        if (LMenuVModel == null)
        {
            LMenuVModel = GetSessionMenu();
        }
        DynModel.MenuViewModel = LMenuVModel;
        DynModel.Employee = _OnEmployee;
        if (trackingItems.Count > 0)
        {
            DynModel.TrackingItems = trackingItems;
            _trackingItems = trackingItems;
        }
        else
        {
            DynModel.TrackingItems = null;
            DynModel.TrackingItems = trackingItems;

        }
        return View(DynModel);
    }
}
```

One thing really weird (and nasty) is the second time through, the Session object has disappeared. In Fact, when I inspect it using breakpoints, I see that the HttpContext.Session.SessionID has changed. But I don't think it can be timeout, since it happens every time at the same place in my code.

I only mention it in case it helps debug this behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your button html, have you tried changing `type="submit"` to `type="button"` -- just a thought.

Comment: @DavidTansey: Good thought. But unfortunately, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way of handling this, but it seems to be working. I'm going to put this up and if no one comes up with a better way, I will close it as the answer.

There was NOTHING I could find that worked to stop the multiple calls into the method. So I changed the pattern.

The overview was I had one view (EMPLOYEE) that was to redirect to the other(ETIME). When I just had Javascript do it, the Javascript was executing twice, in different Sessions -- IDK how that is possible, but that's what it looks like. So, in a rough diagram it was doing this:

[image: fig1]

So, I changed it to use Ajax to call into the EMPLOYEE controller, and pass the info back to the EMPLOYEE Ajax script which then redirected to the ETIME controller and view.

[image: Fig 2]

It still gets called twice, but now I can catch to "false" call, and ignore it with a 205 error. so, it SEEMS to run better now.

Changes to code looks like this:

Button Definition:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<button type="button" id="ViewHoursbutton" name="ViewHours" class="btn btn-primary button-bottom">View Hours</button>
</div>
```

Employee Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GotoHours(string employeeID)
  {
    if (employeeID == null || employeeID == "undefined")
     {
         return NoContent();
     }
// Pass the EmployeeID back to the AJAX Success section 
// which will do the redirect
    var retVal = Json(new { EmployeeID = employeeID });
    return retVal;
}
```

AJAX Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var employeeID = '@Model.Employee.EmployeeID';

  $(document).ready(function () 
  {
                      $("#ViewHoursbutton").off("click").click(function () 
 {
 event.stopPropagation(); 
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Employee/GotoHours",
     data: { employeeID: employeeID },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) 
      {
         // handle the success by making it redirect
       window.location.href = "/ETime/Index?EmployeeID=" + response.EmployeeID;
      },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // handle the error response here, if necessary
       }
    });
  });
```

You can see in the Ajax script I threw everything but the kitchen sink at the button to stop it from double clicking and double sending, but nothing worked.

Anyway... I'll be curious to see if anyone has a better way. I am not deeply experienced in HTML/Ajax ways. But this seems to work.